# is it possible to place new obejct instance to an array directly in constructor?

Tags: php, arrays, constructor

I wrote class method addUser, which creates new user instance and than add its object to an array (collection, yes?), code look like this :

```
public static function addUser($login, $pass, $email) {

    $newuser = new cUser($login, $pass, $email);  //calling constructor

    self::dataLoad();
    self::$D_users[$new_login] = $newuser;        // adding to an array
    self::dataStore();

}
```

What I'm considering is, if is it possible to do this all directly in a constructor? Am I right, that it is not possible?

Comment: not really. the cUser constructor can't read "outside" of itself to modify whatever object addUser is in, unless it's an inherited class or something.

Comment: yes, thats what I was thinking too.